# Suppress/Filter a row

Tags: peoplesoft, bi-publisher

I am fairly new to using PeopleSoft BI Publisher plugin for MS Word and integrating it with PS Query Manager. My question is whether in the RTF file you can put logic to suppress or filter out data?

I have a for-each grouping that prints a line (row). I would like to add logic to NOT print the line if the Witholding amount field (M.WTHD_AMT) is equal to 0 (zero). My question is what would the syntax look like, and where should I place it (on the For Each grouping below, the Field level, or somewhere else?) I know I can alter the PS Query (data source) to do the filtering but I would like to leave that as-is and handle this in the template.

I see that there is another conditional IF statement ("rmt_") so I'm not sure if I can add this additional logic to that element or if I need a separate one. I appreciate any feedback!

[image]

**EDIT:**

I've added a new "Conditional Region" as suggested, and it works with just the WTHD_AMT criteria !0 to zero, however I tried added additional criteria where L.PYMNT_TYPE = 'R' and when I run the process it doesn't display data on the PDF output. Is there something wrong with the syntax? Do I need to have a separate Conditional Region for this 2nd criteria? I've seen another BI report where they have 2 or 3 criteria as part of one element.

`<?if:number(M.WTHD_AMT)!=0.00?> and <?if:L.PYMNT_TYPE='R'?>`

[image]

Comment: I see you are not using Word to show table grid lines, enabling that is a HUGE help when messing with tables in Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Conditional Region' is the button you are looking for.

When using this button, make sure to double check where the if/endif or C/EC elements are added. It tends to ignore the selected element and join the elements to the start and end of the line. You will then need to cut and paste it into the right spot. For you this will probably be right after the F element and before the E element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I edited the post above as I am trying to add additional criteria to this Conditional Region element and I'm not sure if this is possible and if so, whether I'm using the correct syntax.

Comment: @Nick replace the inner '?> and <? if' by 'and'. It has to be inside the code tags.    
 
`<?if:number(M.WTHD_AMT)!=0.00 and L.PYMNT_TYPE='R'?>`
You could also just remove 'and' and nest the if: conditions, but then you'd need 2 closing <?end if?>tags.

Comment: I added the code however I do not get any data returned and I should be. You don't think that the `if:number` is casting the number format onto the `L.PYMNT_TYPE` do you?

Comment: Not unless they changed how brackets work.
Try `<?if:number(M.WTHD_AMT)!=0?><?L.PYMNT_TYPE='R'?>` Your line `<?end if?><?end if?>`

Comment: Are you missing the `if:` for `L.PYMNT_LINE` or is it supposed to be formatted like that? I'll need the two `<?end if?>` statements on the EC element?  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You are correct, it has to be `<?if:L.PYMNT_TYPE='R'?>` and yes 2 times `<?end if?>` to close.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179477/discussion-between-nick-and-peter-paff).

Comment: Peter I don't think it liked that formatting as I got a No Success in Process Monitor. It seems to only run when having it formatted as `<?if:number(M.WTHD_AMT)!=0.00 and L.PYMNT_TYPE='R'?>`. I'll have to keep digging, as this same conditional logic works and retrieves data in my SQL that is being used for the data source.

Comment: Peter just curious if you know of a way to debug this?

Comment: @Nick as I told you in chat, if your process goes to No Success, the log/trace is usually a good place to start.

Comment: @Nick You can also run your PSQuery to XML, load the xml in word via 'Sample XML' and preview if your code results in what you expect.

Comment: Can't access chat now, the process does run successfully if I used the 'and' within the opening and closing tag, however I just don't get the group data displaying when I add `and L.PYMNT_TYPE='R'?` to what I had already existing `<?if:number(M.WTHD_AMT)!=0?>`. Logically what this is doing is it will display a record if the `WTHD_AMT` is **not** equal to zero, and the `PYMNT_TYPE` **is** equal to 'R'. Or is this being evaluated differently? Sorry for all the questions...

Comment: Figured it out! That field `L.PYMNT_TYPE` was not originally in my PS Query (data source) and therefore it did not have a reference to it in the .XML file that was loaded into the RTF document. I added the field in the query and regenerated the XML file and now it returns the data as expected! Just thought I would share. I would be curious to know if there is another way of editing the XML file without having to add a field into the PS Query that won't be used otherwise. Thanks again for your help Peter!

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

You can nest `<?if?>` statements. Just add another `<?end if?>` at the end. Make sure there are no spaces between the all of the *IF* or *END IF* objects at the beginning or end of the content/row, else the row may still be displayed.

**Option 2**

You can add conditions in the repeating section. Below will repeat the region for every *record* where *M.WTHD_AMT* is not *0.00*

`<?for-each:record_path/record[M.WTHD_AMT!='0.00']?>`

Comment: Is there a reason why `<?if:number(M.WTHD_AMT)!=0.00 and L.PYMNT_TYPE='R'?>` should not execute for a Conditional Region element within a for-each group? I want to display records where the `WTHD_AMT` is **not** equal to zero **AND** the `PYMNT_TYPE` **is** equal to 'R'. I'm not getting any records returned though, even when I apply this same logic to my SQL query (used as the data source) I retrieve the row I am expecting.

Comment: Sometimes BI Publisher takes some playing with to figure out what is going on. I hope you found the "Template Viewer" that BI Publisher Desktop installed. It's a tremendous help. You can change and test very quickly.

Comment: I'd have to play with the file and data source to see what exactly the problem is. Decide if you want to compare numbers or text, and stick with that. If you are converting to number, compare against '0' not '0.00'. There's no reason not to use single quotes around your 0 or 0.00, so I'd suggest using them. Do you get data if you use nested if statements? You can fool around with the nesting, and show the variable after the first if, and after second if, see which one is eliminating it. And do that testing in a simple text only template, not one with a table where you're doing it by row.

Comment: I get data if I just use the Conditional Region/code: `<?if:number(M.WTHD_AMT)!=0.00?>` however when I add in the `and L.PYMNT_TYPE='R'?>` that is when I get no data back when the BI publisher process runs. I have the XML file if that would be helpful to look at...

Comment: Figured it out! That field `L.PYMNT_TYPE` was not originally in my PS Query (data source) and therefore it did not have a reference to it in the .XML file that was loaded into the RTF document. I added the field in the query and regenerated the XML file and now it returns the data as expected! Just thought I would share. I would be curious to know if there is another way of editing the XML file without having to add a field into the PS Query that won't be used otherwise.

Comment: For testing purposes, you can use any number of software applications. I found Microsoft XML Notepad to be helpful with viewing and editing XML. It's Free. ...Good to see you found the problem.